# SSD/HD Hybrid Disks

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hybrid-storage

I am currently looking into getting a new hard-drive for my desktop. It is a small one, so it uses laptop HD form-factor. Currently, I have one storage drive that is a regular HD working at 5400RPM and 500GB in capacity. The main disk on which the OSs are loaded is a 1TB Seagate Hybrid drive.

That is, it has 8GB on SSD which serves as a cache for most frequently accessed files. Typically, most OS files end up in the cache, which makes the OS load time very short.

The drive I am needing to replace is the smaller one. After briefly checking out the NewEgg, it appears that hybrid drives may have fallen out of favor. Is that so? Are they still effective? What could be a suitable course of action in my situation?

P.S. I mostly use the smaller drive for storage, but I can see how that may change. Particularly, I may install something like Hackintosh there and do video and music editing in addition to storage.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that SHDDs were largely a stop-gap meadure due to the high cost of SSDs, but thr computing landscape has changed.

- SSDs are now a lot more affordable, so the value proposition in hybrid drives
- Entry level SSDs are now comfortably able to hold the whole OS.
- Many motherboards support m2 slots for ssds
- OS's, motherboards and some fileststems have support for using SSDs (and optane memory which is similar) as cache - they can likely fo a better job the a hard drive.
- SSD performance leaves SHDD for dead.

You can still buy SHDDs (but I wouldnt) - 
https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Description=hybrid%20hard%20drive&Submit=ENE

A typical way to solve the problem is to just buy a larger ssd, or use an SSD for boot os and hard disk /nas /cloud for storage. The SSD does not need to be a SATA disk - but your options depend on your motherboard and storage needs.

A reputable brand 1tb SSD is less then USD $130.  I'd just buy that.

Answer (score 1):

Among power users, they've never really been all that popular.  The unmanaged ones are a pain in the arse to work with (they present as one physical device, but the first part of the storage is SSD while the rest is HDD, and the drive doesn't even show the system where that switch happens), the device managed ones (like it sounds like you have) have been pretty consistently less than optimal in what they choose to cache, and the host-managed ones require special OS support that's not exactly reliable.

Among mainstream consumers, they've also fallen out of favor, as the problems they originally set out to solve is much less of an issue now.  The whole point was to allow large capacity storage while still getting the speed benefits of an SSD, all at a reasonable cost.  The thing is though, prices have come down significantly for SSD's, and most people don't actually need even 500GB of storage space that's that fast, so in almost all cases it makes more sense to get a 250GB (or similar size) SSD for the OS, and a larger HDD for secondary storage.  This sidesteps all the issues with SSHD's while still giving a reasonable 'best of both worlds' approach.

---

Now, realistically in your case, if you can afford to just get a 1TB SSD and replace *both* drives with that, I would suggest doing so.  If not, I'd suggest instead getting a 250GB SSD for the OS disk, and upgrading the other disk to something larger (you can get 2TB conventional HD's for about the same cost as a 250GB SSD).